# rMBP Trackpad slips when trying to scroll?

Tags: trackpad, macbook-pro, macos

Hello I just got my first ever MBP Retina and I was wondering if this is normal :

Sometimes I try to scroll upwards or downwards (natural way) and the mouse moves instead of scrolling the page up and down. Im not sure why this happens, is there a specific way how I should position my fingers on the trackpad ? Or perhaps the distance between each finger ?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, this means you just don't put both fingers at the same time. Try sticking your index and the other finger together and moving your arm or your wrist instead of trying to move the individual fingers. You'll get used to it.

The animated videos in the System Preferences -> Trackpad are a good example of the safest way to do the gesture. Once you get the hang of them, do them like you want, but it's a good starting point.

[image: Scrolling!]

Comment: Further to this, I've noticed if my fingers aren't quite parallel along the horizontal axis, the scrolling gesture won't always activate properly - same problem on the vertical axis when trying to flip back through history in Safari - make sure those fingertips are lined up, not diagonal! :)

Comment: Yes, diagonal means start for zoom or rotate. But, you can have a finger far down and the other far up, as long as they are really near one another.